# Store mutiple select box value and same input field value in serialized form

Tags: php, mysql

```
<!-- html code -->
<form id="wpsc-settings-form" action="" method="post">
<tr class="rate_row">
<td> 
    <input type="text" style="width:160px;" value="3000" name="zipcode[]">
</td>
<td>
    <select multiple="" name="city[]">
        <option value="Abbotsford">Abbotsford</option>
        <option value="Aberfeldie">Aberfeldie</option>
        <option value="Airport West">Airport West</option>
    </select>
</td>
 <td> 
   <input type="text" style="width:160px;" value="3000" name="zipcode[]">
</td>
<td>
    <select multiple="" name="city[]">
        <option value="Abbotsford">Abbotsford</option>
        <option value="Aberfeldie">Aberfeldie</option>
        <option value="Airport West">Airport West</option>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>    
</form>
```

[image]

```
<!-- php code -->
<?php
        $options = $_POST['zipcode'];
        $city = $_POST['city'];  
        $serializeoption = serialize($city);

        foreach($city as $key => $value){
            $simple_shipping_options_city[$options[$key]] = $value;
        }

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($simple_shipping_options_city);
        echo "</pre>";

        update_option('wpsc_simple_shipping_city', $simple_shipping_options_city); // update query
?>
```

The code above works the following way. If I select one city output is like this:

```
 Array
(
[3000] => Abbotsford
[2000] => Airport West
)
```

If I select multiple cities not pass input field value.

I want save single zipcode against mutiple city. Could you please provide suggestions of improvements of the above code?

Comment: in first input field enter 3000, select 2 city and in second input field enter 2000 and select one city i want save data in database like that a:3:{i:3000;s:10:"Abbotsford";i:3000;s:9:"Albanvale";i:2000;s:9:"Albanvale";}

Comment: why down vote my question, please comment , i should come to know where i did mistake

Answer (score 0):

For starters, in this line

```
print_r($simple_shipping_options_city);
```

`simple_shipping_options_city` is an array.  You need to tell the array which index you want to see.

Comment: i want to save like that in database a:2:{i:3000;s:10:"Abbotsford";i:2000;s:9:"Albanvale";}

Comment: in first input enter 3000, select 2 city and in second input enter 2000 and select one city i want save data in database like that a:3:{i:3000;s:10:"Abbotsford";i:3000;s:9:"Albanvale";i:2000;s:9:"Albanvale";}